# Imagen para input type radio

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo unos inputs radio con imagen, pero cuando se hace check me gustaría ponerle un icono (imagen) como que está seleccionado esa opción. No se muy bien porque el before no se muestra, pero con inspeccionar elemento, si que quita o pone el before.

```css
/* HIDE RADIO */
.radioCat input[type=radio] { 
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  /* IMAGE STYLES */
.radioCat input[type=radio] + img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.radioCat img {
    width: 20%;
}
.radioCat input[type=radio]:checked + img:before {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 245px;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Light_green_check.svg/1200px-Light_green_check.svg.png) no-repeat;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="radioCat">
    <label style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="{{ $ico->slug }}" checked>
        <img src="https://www.pequeocio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/costillas-cerdo-horno.jpg" class="radioCatImg">
    </label>
    
    <label style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="{{ $ico->slug }}">
        <img src="https://www.pequeocio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/costillas-cerdo-horno.jpg" class="radioCatImg">
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los selectores `::before` y `::after`, según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> Los pseudoelementos generados por `::before` y `::after` son contenidos por la caja de formato del elemento, y por lo tanto, no aplica a elementos de reemplazo como los elementos `<img>`, o `<br>`.

#### Solución:

Podrías agregar, por ejemplo, un `<picture>` (*o cualquier otro elemento*) que contenga las imagenes

**Ejemplo**:

```css
/* HIDE RADIO */
.radioCat input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
/* IMAGE STYLES */
.radioCat img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.radioCat picture {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.radioCat input:checked+picture::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Light_green_check.svg/1200px-Light_green_check.svg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioCat">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" checked/>
    <picture>
    <img src="https://www.pequeocio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/costillas-cerdo-horno.jpg" class="radioCatImg"/>
    </picture>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="2"/>
    <picture>
      <img src="https://www.pequeocio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/costillas-cerdo-horno.jpg" class="radioCatImg"/>
    </picture>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona estupendo @Marcos muchisimas gracias!!!!